# Media controller progress doesn't updated

Tags: android, media-player, media, android-videoview, progress

I am trying to play video with media controller the problem is that the progress of media controller updated to 0.2 seconds then stop until i  press pause or any other button of the controller it is updated to the actual progress my code is as following:

```
   MediaController mc = new MediaController(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    mc.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ((ViewGroup) mc.getParent()).removeView(mc);
    mc.findFocus();
    mc.setEnabled(true);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    LayVideoPlayer.addView(mc);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(videoModel.getVideoUrl());
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```